# Why doesn't cabal build Eval.hs?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I downloaded xmonad-extras-0.10.1.2 and ran the following:
xmonad-extras.cabal: http://hpaste.org/78707

```
$cabal configure
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring xmonad-extras-0.10.1.2...

$cabal build
Building xmonad-extras-0.10.1.2...
Preprocessing library xmonad-extras-0.10.1.2...
In-place registering xmonad-extras-0.10.1.2...

It seems ok but there is no compiled Eval.

$find . -name "*.o"
./dist/build/XMonad/Util/WindowPropertiesRE.o
./dist/build/XMonad/Prompt/MPD.o
./dist/build/XMonad/Actions/Volume.o
./dist/build/HSxmonad-extras-0.10.1.2.o

$find . -name "Eval*"
./XMonad/Prompt/Eval.hs
./XMonad/Actions/Eval.hs

Then i tried use Setup.lhs directly:
$runghc Setup.lhs configure
Configuring xmonad-extras-0.10.1.2...
Setup.lhs: At least the following dependencies are missing:
X11 >=1.4.3, mtl -any, xmonad ==0.10.*, xmonad-contrib ==0.10.*

$ghc-pkg list|grep -i xmonad
xmonad-0.10
xmonad-contrib-0.10
```

It is strange , any suggestion is appreciated !

Comment: For the second part, the `runghc ./Setup.lhs` way uses global installs by default, and thus can only use packages from the global db unless you explicitly pass the `--user` flag to the configure step. `cabal install` by default makes user installs. The "missing" libraries are in your user db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick glance, it looks like the Eval modules are only built if you set the `with_hint` flag when configuring the package.

```
$ cabal configure -f with_hint
```

Comment: cabal configure --f with_hint works even if hint package has fatal error